# When a child process is created with fork, the parent ID is not as the same as the parent ID

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, fork

In order to explain the question I'm asking let's consider this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {    
    pid_t child, parent;
    parent = getpid();
    printf("Main parent pid: %d\n",parent );

    if((child = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
    } else if(child  == 0 ) {
        printf("A Child process is created, pid: %d, ppid: %d \n", 
             getpid(), getppid());  
    } else if(child > 0) {  
        printf("Parent says: Child pid: %d, getpid: %d, getppid: %d\n", 
               child, getpid(), getppid()); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code on terminal I get such an output

```
Main pid: 711 

Parent says: Child pid: 712, getpid: 711, getppid: 598 

A Child process is created, pid: 712, ppid: 1
```

As far as I understand, when I'm creating a new process by forking from a already created process, the parent of this new process must the process that I have forked.Hovewer, as you can see from the output, the parent process ID of the child is 1, i.e the init process, so why is that so ? Is my understand wrong, or there is some other things that I'm not seeing ?

Note: I'm working on Mac OSX.

Comment: That is a horrid layout.  If you program in Pico, use it.  If you program in C, use an orthodox C layout — not that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the parent process (711) has died and the child process inherited by the init process (1) before it gets to report.  If you have the parent wait for the child to die before exiting itself, you'll see the result you expect.

To demonstrate:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t child, parent;
    parent = getpid();
    printf("Main parent pid: %d\n", (int)parent);

    if ((child = fork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    else if (child  == 0)
    {
        printf("A Child process is created, pid: %d, ppid: %d\n",
               (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    }
    else if (child > 0)
    {
        printf("Parent says: Child pid: %d, getpid: %d, getppid: %d\n",
               (int)child, (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
#ifndef DO_NOT_WAIT_FOR_CHILD
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
#endif
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled without `-DDO_NOT_WAIT_FOR_CHILD`, I got the sample output:

```
Main parent pid: 77646
Parent says: Child pid: 77647, getpid: 77646, getppid: 46383
A Child process is created, pid: 77647, ppid: 77646
Child 77647 exited with status 0x0000
```

When compiled with `-DDO_NOT_WAIT_FOR_CHILD`, I got the sample output:

```
Main parent pid: 77662
Parent says: Child pid: 77663, getpid: 77662, getppid: 46383
A Child process is created, pid: 77663, ppid: 1
```

Comment: I tested what you have said, and worked, thank you :)